# How do I let my task-handler function accept a default POST request from GAE pushqueue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, flask-restplus

I am using python and flask rest_plus. I wrote a push task and pushed to a queue with GAE. By default the queue pushes the message of the task to the handler by a POST request. Is there a way I can make my task-handler function accept a POST request , so that it can enter my task handler body and execute my task. Currently I am getting a 405 method not allowed error in the logs . Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `post()` method as your task-handler function, instead of a `get()`method, see [Full Example](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/example.html) from the official rest_plus doc.

Alternatively, you can change the HTTP method of the [push task to GET](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#passing_data) when creating it, default is POST.

Comment: Does making the function name post() instead of get() , make the handler only accept POST?

Comment: Yes, which probably makes sense if you want to implement a REST API (HTTP verbs have a meaning). However, the Flask docs explain how you can have one implementation support [multiple methods](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/views/#method-hints). Alternatively , if you want to use the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header see [Adding HTTP Method Overrides](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/methodoverrides/).